# How do I replace the battery icon with just a percentage, not both?

Tags: icons, battery, statusbar

How do I replace the battery icon with just the percentage of the battery, not both?

I am using Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing third party applet indicator:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then use dconf and configure like so:

- "remove" show present
- enable "show percentage"

Comment: so i found com/canonical/indicator/power/  and it lets me toggle the icon, but when the icon is off, the percentage doesn't show either. Is that what you were suggesting? i cant find any other dir in dconf that has the indicator.

Comment: Sorry if this workaround wasn't successful, was  thinking along those lines..All the best,if I get a successful workaround will notify

Comment: but my reasoning was that if you disable "present" policy and enable "show percentage" it would achieve the desired result

Comment: oh ok, well thanks man, i appreciate the effort... where did the indicator applet install to? maybe i did something wrong...